# Ampersand in Windows Password

Tags: windows, batch-file, perforce

I have a password for a Perforce account which contains an ampersand (&) and when I try to use certain P4 commands, I get the following error:

```
Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the ampersand causing the password to not be recognized in the Windows command shell, however I am more familiar with bash than with Windows, so I'm not sure how to handle this. Any Windows experts out there that have seen something like this? I'd like to avoid having to change the password if possible but somehow set my P4PASSWD environment variable such that it is recognized by the shell as the correct password.

Comment: You might want to try SuperUser.

Comment: @user3270760 He means the SuperUser website, this question fits there better. Good luck! :)

Comment: Sorry. I mean the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) stack echange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is used to chain commands together in windows command shells. If you want to use a literal `&` in a command-line argument, you'll have to quote it

Unquoted. Executes as two separate "echo" calls:

```
C:\Users\marc>echo foo & echo bar
foo
bar
```

Quoted: Executes one single echo call and doesn't see two echo calls - just one

```
C:\Users\marc>echo foo "&" echo bar
foo "&" echo bar
```

Comment: But what if I do something like this to escape the ampersand: 
`C:\Users> set pw=t^&r3`

Then, I get output like this:
`C:\Users> echo %pw%`
t
'r3' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting P4PASSWD, use the 'p4 login' command.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_login.html